# R (...) not defined because of singularities

Tags: r

I've data, is include some 'NA' part. Full data set size is 1994 obs. but i use 'complete.cases' formula, so control_dataset size is 319 obs.

However, I started this code :

```
zero_2nd <-lm(formula = ViolentCrimesPerPop ~ (population + householdsize + 
            racePctHisp + agePct12t29 + agePct65up + numbUrban + pctWWage + 
            pctWFarmSelf + pctWInvInc + pctWSocSec + medFamInc + perCapInc + 
            AsianPerCap + NumUnderPov + PctPopUnderPov + PctNotHSGrad + 
            PctBSorMore + PctUnemployed + PctEmploy + PctEmplManu + PctOccupManu + 
            PctOccupMgmtProf + TotalPctDiv + PctFam2Par + PctKids2Par + 
            PctYoungKids2Par + PctWorkMomYoungKids + NumImmig + PctImmigRecent + 
            PctImmigRec8 + PctImmigRec10 + PctRecentImmig + PctRecImmig8 + 
            PctRecImmig10 + PctSpeakEnglOnly + PctLargHouseFam + PctLargHouseOccup + 
            PersPerRentOccHous + PctPersDenseHous + PctHousLess3BR + 
            PctHousOwnOcc + PctWOFullPlumb + OwnOccMedVal + OwnOccHiQuart + 
            RentLowQ + MedRent + MedRentPctHousInc + MedOwnCostPctInc + 
            NumStreet + PctForeignBorn + LemasSwFTPerPop + LemasTotReqPerPop + 
            PolicPerPop + RacialMatchCommPol + PctPolicAsian + OfficAssgnDrugUnits + 
            PctUsePubTrans + PolicCars)^2, data = zerodata)
```

and I use summary(zero_2nd),
Residuals:
ALL 319 residuals are 0: no residual degrees of freedom!

Coefficients: (1393 not defined because of singularities)
are occur.

and all Std. Error, t value, Pr(>|t|) is NA.

Why this situation has occur? and how can solve this problem?

(zerodata = cutted data set (319 obs.))

Comment: I tried out your syntax with some randomly generated data using `rnorm()`. The `lm()` function seemed to be working okay on my end, so I don't think it's a syntax issue. Have you met the test assumptions before performing your multiple linear regression (normality, homoscedasticity, no multi-collinearity, etc.)?

Comment: Perhaps some of your covariates are factor variables? That might explain why there are 1393 undefined coefficients, and the fact that all residuals are 0.

Comment: @Zslice : i don't know why "1393" undefined coefficients occur.
and no factor data set. all data is numeric

Comment: @spacedSparking : real raw data has some NA, i make some data set what replaced NA data use mean or median set.
(therefore, i have 3 data set ; mean_replaced / median_replaced / removedNA (= control_dataset) )
but mean_replaced & median_replaced dataset are no make errors. (so i not tried additional test assumptions) 
just, removed set (i told this is  'control_dataset') is makes 'defined because of singularities' occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a statistical question rather than a coding one. Essentially, such an error means that one of the covariates you're using in the model is predicted perfectly by another one.

You can find more details from [a similar question asked on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/182950/coefficients-5-not-defined-because-of-singularities/183211).